Calculated coordinates in TikZ-Paths
I require coordinates in a TikZ-path, which are calculated from values in a table or in a csv-file. Therefore I cannot create the coordinates using the calc-library but have to incorporate additional macros (e.g. \pgfmathsetmacro).
The background for that is drawing onto geographical maps, wherein the coordinates are calculated from latitude and longitude, which have to be taken for certain locations from a table or a csv-file. For example the macro "\location{Vienna}" should yield the coordinate which can be directly used in a TikZ-path. The problem is not the calculation itself, but the result is not recognized as a valid coordinate (although it looks like).
The following MWE shows the problem; \pta works flawlessly, \ptb does not:
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\def\pta#1{(2+#1,4*#1-2)}

\def\ptb#1{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xx}{2+#1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\yy}{4*#1-2}
  (\xx,\yy)
}

\pta{1} \dots\ o.k.\par
\ptb{1} \dots\ also o.k., looks like a valid coordinate

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (10,10);
\fill [red] (0,0) rectangle \pta{2}; % o.k.
\fill [blue] (0,0) rectangle \ptb{2}; % not o.k.!
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Is there a possibility to calculate coordinates using a macro, which itself contains macros (e.g. fetching values from a table or a csv-File)?

My mind is heading toward calculating each component externally, then inputting them individually... similar to here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/727949/319072. My initial impression is that the approach in the question could be improved in this way.

The reason those aren't valid coordinates is because you cannot \pgfmathsetmacro inside a path like that.

please don't use minimal for examples. it isn't intended for this. it's unfortunately named.

if you remove (\xx,\yy) from the definition, you can do \ptb{2} \fill [blue] (0,0) rectangle (\xx,\yy);. does that help? or you could define separate macros for \ptbxx and \ptbyy and then just use those to define the coordinate inline, probably.


Could this serve your purposes?  I'm defending the coordinates separately.
The code
\documentclass[11pt, margin=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\def\pta#1{(2+#1,4*#1-2)}

\tikzmath{
  function xPtB(\t) {
    return 2 +\t;
  };
  function yPtB(\t) {
    return 4*\t -2;
  };
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (10,10);
  \fill [red] (0,0) rectangle \pta{2}; % o.k.
  \fill [blue] (0,0) rectangle ({xPtB(1.8)}, {yPtB(1.8)}); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

